# How do you write a math proof for a congruence that mod's with an offset?

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

How do you write a math proof for a congruences that mod's with an offset?

I'm looking for how to properly form the proof for a congruency i found
that uses an offset at each mod point, an offset the same length from a powers
of two number. For example, when i use the powers of two to mod, i subtact from
it the same length, at each step down, an offset that is the same for each mod
of that powers of two offset.

Here is an eample of what i'm talking about:

Ok, say I found a congruency that i think you write in the form of:

> When $x$ is a mersenne number greater or equal to $2^7-1$ then:
> $$x \cdot x + x \equiv 0 \pmod{x.\operatorname{bit\_length}() \cdot x.\operatorname{bit\_length}()}$$

Here is an example of the congruency:

```
x=2**7-1
(x * x + x) = 16256

iteration, mathoperation, result, ( explanation )
0, 16256 % 8185 = 8071 ( 8185 which is 8192-x.bit_length())
1, 8071 % 4089 = 3982 ( 4089 which is 4096-x.bit_length())
2, 3982 % 2041 = 1941 ( 2041 which is 2048-x.bit_length())
3, 1941 % 1017 = 924 ( 1017 which is 1024-x.bit_length())
4, 924 % 505 = 505 ( 505 which is 512-x.bit_length())
5, 419 % 249 = 249 ( 249 which is 256-x.bit_length())
6, 170 % 121 = 49 ( ( 121 which is 128-x.bit_length())

at the bitlength iteration it lands on 49.

49 ( Whose factors are 7*7 ) hence the congruency of (this is what i'm not 
sure of how to write correctly):
(x * x + x) ≡ 0 (mod x.bit_length()*x.bit_length()) ?
```

This works for every mersenne number with this equation.
For numbers less than $2^7-1$ the congruence shows up before
the last iteration of the bitlength, so i'm not sure if
that counts as part of the proof. If you use $2^{13}-1$, you land
on $169$, which is $13 \cdot 13$. and so forth as you go up in numbers

My goal is to know the math proof for this, i think it's something
like:

> When $x$ is a mersenne number greater or equal to $2^7-1$ then:
> $$x \cdot x + x \equiv 0 \pmod{x.\operatorname{bit\_length}() \cdot x.\operatorname{bit\_length}()}$$

but i don't know how to account for the modding offset from the powers
of two in the proof, which is the $\operatorname{bit\_length}$ of $x$ at each mod point. so for $4096$ it is
$4089$, for $2048$ it is $2041$, for $1024$ it is $1017$, for $512$ it is $505$, for $256$ it is $249$, and for $128$ it is $121$,
which are all the powers of two, minus the $\operatorname{bit\_length}()$, of the mersenne number.

Thanks for any help or guidance here on how to deal with proofs that deal with offsets from the powers of two.

Comment: In your computation, you wrote `0, 16256 % 8185 = 8071 ( 8185 which is 8092-x.bit_length())` and `2, 3982 % 2041 = 1941 ( 2041 which is 2046-x.bit_length())`, but $2^{12} = 8192 \neq 8092$ and $2^{11} = 2048 \neq 2046$.

Comment: I fixed those errors, thank you for catching them